# How do you specify the exact order of Minitest tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest, testunit

Minitest lets you run tests in order by overriding `test_order` to `alpha`. (You can also use the `i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!` method.)

After doing this, how do you control the order the tests are run across multiple files?
Is there a way to run some tests from one file and then switch to another file?

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/fa02ad1598b1634f5894b9474952937b8a5cdb89/lib/minitest/test.rb#L69), it seems one should be able to control how methods are sorted. But how do you specify that order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!` (or `def self.test_order; :alpha;end` define an alphabetic order.

Beside the alphabetic order there is only a random order defined (at least in 'minitest', '>5.5.1', '<=5.6.1'.

But you can patch `MiniTest::Test.runnable_methods` to get another order.

```
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class MiniTest::Test
    #Add a test order :defined
    def self.runnable_methods
      methods = methods_matching(/^test_/)

      case self.test_order
      when :random, :parallel then
        max = methods.size
        methods.sort.sort_by { rand max }
      when :defined then  # <-new
        methods
      when :alpha, :sorted then
        methods.sort
      else
        raise "Unknown test_order: #{self.test_order.inspect}"
      end
    end
end

class TestOrder < MiniTest::Test
  def self.test_order; :defined; end

  #Alphabetic order
  #~ def self.test_order; :alpha;end
  #~ i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!

  def test_4;    p __method__;  end
  def test_3;    p __method__;  end
  def test_2;    p __method__;  end
  def test_1;    p __method__;  end
end
```

But the test order is only defined per Test-subclass, not global for all tests. So this does not give you access to the order of test methods in multiple test classes.

I estimate you have different test-classes in your files, so this would correspond to your problem. (Not the files is the criteria, but the Test-class.)

If you define only one Test class in your test files then you have the possibility to define your own order.

Comment: Thanks. Can you test multiple controllers from within one test class? Since [get](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/actionpack/4.2.1/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior#get-instance_method) seems to work with the given controller.

Comment: @Ari Sorry, I'm not  a rails-user, so I can't help for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can add [i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html#method-c-i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent-21) to your test class.

Example:

```
class TestClass < Minitest::Unit::TestCase

  i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!

  def test_true
    assert true
  end

end
```

According to [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html#method-c-i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent-21),

> Call this at the top of your tests when you absolutely positively need to have ordered tests. In doing so, you’re admitting that you suck and your tests are weak.

You can also simply add the following to your test class:

```
def self.test_order
 :alpha
end
```

The i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent! method uses that.

Comment: I reference that in my question. How do you specify the exact order after that?

Comment: You can define test_order as either :alphabetical, :random, or :defined. I believe that you are looking for :defined. Check this out: http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/en/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#test_order=-class_method

Comment: @AlexPan The actual [version 5.6.1 of Minitest](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest/versions/5.6.1) does not support test_order :defined. Whch version do you use?

Comment: @knut Is there any way to define an overall order for the tests with 5.6.1?

Comment: @ari Not by my knowledge - some details in my post. It is a bit too long for a comment. I use minitest only  for some days, so maybe there is a solution for your problem. Let's wait for some other answers,

Answer (score 0):

Can also change globally for all test suits:

```
# in your test_helper.rb
require "minitest" # or "minitest/autorun"
class Minitest::Test
  def self.test_order
   :alpha
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Little addition ( or may be override %) ) to @knut answer. You don't need to patch Minitest, instead just override self.runnable_methods in your TestClass, and place your tests there in any suitable order.

```
def self.runnable_methods
   super | ['run_last']
end
```

It's better then @knuts answer since original answer is dependent internally on Module method instance_methods(include_super=true), and it will return them in less predictable and partially alphabetically sorted way:

```
 module A
   def method3()  end
 end
 class B
   include A
   def method2()  end
 end
 class C < B
   def method4() end
   def method1()  end
 end
 C.instance_methods(true) # -> [:method1, :method4, :method2, :method3 ...
```

so I assume in previously given solution your tests will need alpha sorted names to keep their order. So looks like it's just another way around to :alpha or :sorted way